# Angularjs using once the value from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages">
<input type="text" ng-model="page.name"
</div>
```

Basically this will show page.name multiple times for same name. Problem is my data being returned is in collection so I cant just use the name property. 
Can you please tell me how can i just show page.name only once.

Comment: If you need just the first element from an array when some data comes back you should just pull that piece of data off and put it in another property on the scope that you can access.  Ng-repeat is made for the use case of repeating a portion of DOM for each element in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still say your better off pulling this data into it's own property but here's a lazy way to achieve the goal:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="pages[0].name"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.pages = [{name:"Page1"},{name:"Page2"}];
})
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UmRSVek3psKoklxVKBfI?p=preview